# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

I'm pretty sure I left a comment to:

[How was Volkswagen able to trick the lab pollution test?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5570/how-was-volkswagen-able-to-trick-the-lab-pollution-test/5575#5575)

Yet now it isn't there. Why was it deleted? And why I cannot find ANY trace of my prose anywhere in the SE interface? The only reason I can see for its deletion is being off-topic, which it wasn't.

Answer (score 3):

Please keep in mind that [comments are second class citizens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/194162) in the realm of StackExchange.  It's one of the key differences that sets StackExchange apart from other sites.

As an off-shoot of that premise, comments aren't searchable - which is by design.  The only users who are able to see deleted comments are moderators and StackOverflow employees who have a diamond for that particular site.

---

To address some of your specific questions:

> I'm pretty sure I left a comment to:

You did, and yes, it was deleted.  I cleared out quite a few comments on that post after a flag had been raised.

> And why I cannot find ANY trace of my prose anywhere in the SE interface?

See above about comments not being searchable.

> Why was it deleted? ... The only reason I can see for its deletion is being off-topic, which it wasn't.

It wasn't off-topic, but it also wasn't constructive for the main question or that particular answer.

Your comment was:

> Hence the interest for open-source software being requested by and
>   submitted to the regulator for auditing purposes (or double-checking
>   if fraud is suspected). Manufacturers should submit their source-code
>   to the regulators, just as they submit their hardware for testing...

In different circumstances, I probably wouldn't have deleted the comment.  However, it was one of 18 comments on that post and the comments were beginning to turn into a separate conversation diverging away from the main gist of the question.

Comments aren't meant for side conversations - that's what [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20403/the-skunk-works) is for.  Leaving your comment in place would have invited a response from others which would have led the comment thread further away from the main point of the post.  It's a conversation that would have been better held in our chat room.

So let's circle back to the point that comments aren't meant to hold lasting, meaningful information.  They're subject to deletion as circumstances dictate.

A comment being deleted doesn't necessarily imply anything about the person making the comment.  The deletion simply means that the comment wasn't constructive for the main purpose of the post.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. SE can be a very frustrating experience for users, especially users with low privileges. Re scope of comments: While they're 2nd class citizens indeed, comments are often crucial to completing an answer or putting it into context. As such, sometimes comments have more value than the answers themselves. Re my comment: I do believe it was constructive. The answer discusses at length cheating- as well as regulatory- strategies, and how the manufacturer used software aimed at cheating the tests. I pointed out a different, and appropriate regulatory strategy...

Comment: @landroni The metric here is not whether a comment is constructive or valuable in and of itself; it has to be viewed in the context of the corresponding question and/or answer. In that context your comment, though interesting, is at best tangential. If you feel strongly, though, you might consider writing up a complete and independent answer that expands on that comment in the context of the VW scandal.

Comment: @Air Somewhat tangential, true. Yet it added to the discussion in the context of the answer. Deciding what to leave in/out (as it was done in this case, without obvious off-topic or abuse reasons) is necessarily a trade-off exercise, and in my humble view there was more value to keeping the comment than deleting it... The scope of my intervention was exactly that, a "comment", and I don't think transforming it into an answer is necessary or, indeed, fully pertinent to the actual question... All said and done, being too neat can be as harmful as being too messy...

Comment: @landroni - you're missing a key point.  There _shouldn't be_ discussions around questions and answers.  Discussions in comments devolves the site into a forum which decreases the overall quality of the site.

Comment: @GlenH7 As I mentioned earlier, comments can complete or qualify an answer, by exposing an omission or a fatal weakness in reasoning. This is incredibly useful and increases the quality of the site.

Comment: Yes, but your comment did neither of those, whereas the 8 comments that Glen chose not to delete did directly address the subject of the answer. If yours had been the only comment, there would have been no real need to delete it. Unfortunately, that's not the circumstance here.